# angular2 : issue with rest api

Tags: javascript, rest, angular

I am trying to learn angular2 (coming from php scripts, it is quite difficult^^), using a real rest api in "Tour of Heroes".
From what I read, I thought it could be simple...

I have a working api, built with Express :

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:3001/heroes
[{"_id":"58185c8a8af4b512c51c0519","no":"1","name":"bahamut","__v":0,"updated_at":"2016-11-01T09:12:42.803Z"},{"_id":"58185ca78af4b512c51c051a","no":"2","name":"gatz","__v":0,"updated_at":"2016-11-01T09:13:11.063Z"},{"_id":"58185ec98af4b512c51c051b","no":"3","nam...
```

In hero.service.ts, I can get the data :

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> { // {{{
    console.log('getheroes in service');
    console.log( "%o", this.http.get(this.heroesUrl).toPromise()); 
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  } // }}}
```

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Uml.png)

When I do same console.log on original "Tour of Heroes", I have an array in data whereas here I have a string...
I guess I have to convert somewhere the string but whatever I tried, it does not work.

(I read many examples with Observable too but I have not succeeded either)

Help wanted to explain me how to...
TIA

JP

Comment: What contentType does http://localhost:3001/heroes respond with?

Comment: have you considered JSON.parse(<your response string>)

Answer (score 1):

You're so close! The mistake here is in how you handle Promises, along with  misunderstanding how they return. In this case you were trying to assign an undefined property (`response.json().data`) when you meant to coerce `response.json()` as type `Hero[]` then return.

What you'll need to do is ensure you have a matching type to assign your response when it's converted to a JSON with that `json()` call. The `Hero` type in the guide does not match your response, and you'll have errors because of that.

To check that you're receiving a response, make a call to the service's `getHeroes()` function and log the returned value. Logging internally to the function can be done, but that would be where understanding how Promises work in depth would help more than anything.

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then((response) => response.json() as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

If you want to know I'm not crazy, here's the code to log internally. This should log your response no matter what type is received.

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then((response) => {
                 console.log(response.json());
               })
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

For further context into why you do these `then()` calls, **a Promise returns asynchronously** which means the result is only available after an indeterminate amount of time has passed. Any execution that must wait for the result must either happen in the `then()` calls or after the function returns an actual value. As JS functions run synchronously if you try to execute the following example you'll see a printout of `undefined` rather than a string response. This is because the `console.log(r)` is called immediately after the promise call, completely oblivious to the fact it hasn't actually let `r` be assigned a value.

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
      var r;
      this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then((response) => r = response.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);
      console.log(r);

}
```

Comment: Impressive ! You solved my issue quickly. Even some points are clearer, I still have to learn more on js and () and so on... (I do not know where json() comes from for example).